# Sort multidimensional array by keys - fails on duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a function `sortBy()` that I use to sort multidimensional arrays by a particular key. Here is a sample array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [type] => 1
        [game] => 1
        [platform] => 0
        [TotalPot] => 7550
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [type] => 0
        [game] => 2
        [platform] => 0
        [TotalPot] => 7500
    )

)
```

Here is the function

```
function sortBy($arr, $field='id', $order=1) {
    $a = array();
    if ( !is_array($arr) )
        return false;
    foreach($arr as $subArr) {
        $a[$subArr[$field]] = $subArr;
    }

    if ( $order == 1 ) sort($a);
    else rsort($a);

    return $a;
}
```

In this case, calling `sortBy($array, 'TotalPot');` would work fine, because the two values for `TotalPot` are different. However, if you run this example and set both `TotalPot` fields to $7500, it overwrites the first occurrence with the latter.

What would be the best way to make this function allow for two items with the same value but still keep them in relevant order? I thought about adding another character, an `A` or `1` to the end, but this seems sloppy and not very predictable, so a better course of action would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code and just use `usort()`, e.g.

```
function sortArrayByField(array &$arr, $field = "id", $ASC = TRUE) {
    usort($arr, function($a, $b)use($field, $ASC){
        if($a[$field] == $b[$field])
            return 0;
        return $a[$field] > $b[$field] ? $ASC : !$ASC;
    });
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
sortArrayByField($array, "TotalPot", TRUE);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason they are getting overwritten is because you're creating an array where the index is the value of the totalPot.

If there are duplicates, then you will only have one array element with the totalPot.

Easiest way is just to usort this:

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        "id" => 4,
        "type" => 1,
        "game" => 1,
        "platform" => 0,
        "TotalPot" => 7550
    ], [
        "id" => 5,
        "type" => 0,
        "game" => 2,
        "platform" => 0,
        "TotalPot" => 7500
    ]
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['TotalPot'] - $b['TotalPot'];
});

print_r($array);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/64514efcac5d45):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [type] => 0
            [game] => 2
            [platform] => 0
            [TotalPot] => 7500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [type] => 1
            [game] => 1
            [platform] => 0
            [TotalPot] => 7550
        )

)
```

You can also make this a function:

```
function sortBy($arr, $field='id', $order=1) {
    usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($field, $order) {
        if ($order == 1)
            return $a[$field] - $b[$field];
        else
            return $b[$field] - $a[$field];
    });
}
```